# Oracle DBCA create DB warning with no OracleDBConsoleorcl service created as expected

Tags: dbca

I am creating my first Oracle DB on my Win 2012 R2. But it can success, but the OracleDBConsoleorcl is not created successfully:
[emca error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQwRH.jpg)

I'm attaching my emca log here:

```
Jul 10, 2017 3:40:43 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.util.GeneralUtil  initSQLEngineLoacly
CONFIG: SQLEngine created successfully and connected
Jul 10, 2017 3:40:45 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager checkListenerStatusForDBControl
CONFIG: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLFatalErrorException: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLEngine.executeImpl(SQLEngine.java:1655)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.sqlEngine.SQLEngine.executeSql(SQLEngine.java:1903)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.checkListenerStatusForDBControl(ParamsManager.java:3230)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.unlockMGMTAccount(EMReposConfig.java:1001)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.invoke(EMReposConfig.java:346)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.invoke(EMReposConfig.java:158)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig.perform(EMConfig.java:253)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.em.EMConfiguration.run(EMConfiguration.java:583)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.em.EMConfigStep.executeImpl(EMConfigStep.java:139)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:210)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.callStep(BasicStep.java:251)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.PostDBConfigureStep.executeImpl(PostDBConfigureStep.java:269)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:210)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.Step.execute(Step.java:140)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepContext$ModeRunner.run(StepContext.java:2667)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Jul 10, 2017 3:40:45 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
SEVERE: Listener is not up or database service is not registered with it. Start the Listener and register database service and run EM Configuration Assistant again .
Refer to the log file at D:\Oracle\cfgtoollogs\dbca\orcl\emConfig.log for more details.
Jul 10, 2017 3:40:45 PM oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig perform
CONFIG: Stack Trace: 
oracle.sysman.emcp.exception.EMConfigException: Listener is not up or database service is not registered with it. Start the Listener and register database service and run EM Configuration Assistant again .
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.ParamsManager.checkListenerStatusForDBControl(ParamsManager.java:3245)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.unlockMGMTAccount(EMReposConfig.java:1001)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.invoke(EMReposConfig.java:346)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMReposConfig.invoke(EMReposConfig.java:158)
    at oracle.sysman.emcp.EMConfig.perform(EMConfig.java:253)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.em.EMConfiguration.run(EMConfiguration.java:583)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.em.EMConfigStep.executeImpl(EMConfigStep.java:139)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:210)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.callStep(BasicStep.java:251)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.dbca.backend.PostDBConfigureStep.executeImpl(PostDBConfigureStep.java:269)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.BasicStep.execute(BasicStep.java:210)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.Step.execute(Step.java:140)
    at oracle.sysman.assistants.util.step.StepContext$ModeRunner.run(StepContext.java:2667)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

But my listener is already up:

```
D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 31-JUL-2017 11:33:35

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
```

I'm also attaching my listner.ora screenshot

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\Oracle
```

My tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

MYORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = orcl)
    )
  )
```

If I manually start the listener, it will say it already started.

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.1.

My problem is, the orcl DB is created successful. But there is one Windows Service OracleDBConsoleorcl is not available, see my error:
[missing DBConsole service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlnhG.jpg)

The problem will resurface at always even if I re-run DBCA again (didn't change anything).

My service naming test (via Net manager) is successful.

Comment: can anyone help? thanks a lot

Comment: can anyone have a look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this on myself.

I changed HOSTNAME in the tnsnames.ora as real hostname rather than localhost.

Then several times it displayed no listener.

I tried some steps at:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/oracle-dbca-utility-listener-is-not-up-or-database-service-is-not-registered-w

finally it works successful.